# Overloading operator not working in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

Why is it that below code is always returning the last player in the array?

The operator `bool operator > (Player &P) { return Age > P.Age; }`seems not to be working properly. I see it as "compare the age of the element in the left object to the age of the element in the right object". Any suggestions?

Note: I don't intend to use `std::vector` or `std::string`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Player {
    int Age;
    char *Name;
public:
    Player() {}
    void setName(char *n) { Name = n; }
    void setAge(int a) { Age = a; }
    bool operator > (Player &P) { return Age > P.Age; }
    void showName(){ cout << Name; }
};

int main()
{
    Player *ArrayPlayers = new Player[2];
    ArrayPlayers[0].setName("Player1");
    ArrayPlayers[0].setAge(27);
    ArrayPlayers[1].setName("Player2");
    ArrayPlayers[1].setAge(29);
    ArrayPlayers[2].setName("Player3");
    ArrayPlayers[2].setAge(24);

    Player *Oldest = &ArrayPlayers[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        Player *Current = &ArrayPlayers[i];
        if (Current > Oldest) {
            Oldest = Current;
        }
    }

    cout << "Oldest player is: ";
    Oldest->showName();
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: You are comparing *pointers*.

Comment: If this is supposed to be C++, you should really drop char pointers and use a string class like `std::string`. It will resolve 50% of your debugging troubles.

Comment: You access out of bounds of `ArrayPlayers`. It has two entries, `[0]` and `[1]`, however you write to `[2]` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you are comparing pointers (`Player*`) not `Player` instances. The simplest fix to achieve the desired result is to dereference:

```
if (*Current > *Oldest) {
```

This will invoke your `operator>` implementation for the `Player` class.